# Image is not displayed on hover with <br>

Tags: html, css

I was creating a simple effect for a webpage. I wanted to show an image when mouse is hovered on a link. The problem is, when I use `<br>` tag, image is not shown on hover, but when I remove `<br>` it works.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here? Why does the `<br>` obstruct the hover? Here's a snippet showing that `<br>` is not working:

```css
.imageClass{ 
  display: none; 
} 

a:hover + .imageClass{ 
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<a href="http://esmartify.com/">Esmartify</a>
<br>
<!--When i remove this line, image is shown on hover, otherwise not-->
<div class="imageClass">
  <img src="images6/concert.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

Here's a snippet showing **it is working without `<br>`**:

```css
.imageClass {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + .imageClass {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <a href="http://esmartify.com/">Esmartify</a>
<!--When i remove this line, image is shown on hover, otherwise not-->
<div class="imageClass">
  <img src="images6/concert.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please tell.

Comment: I know it is working without `<br>` . My question was why is this behaving like this because of a <br>. Atleast Try to understand the question properly and then downvote. Have some sense while downvoting.

Comment: I also think that this question shouldn't be downvoted!

Comment: It doesn't seem like a duplicate to me!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `br` behaves as an element between the link and the div. If so, `a:hover ~ .imageClass` should work.

Answer (score 0):

`a:hover + .imageClass` - imageClass must be immediately after link, remove `br` and add to css `display:block` for link

or try to use: `a:hover ~ .imageClass`